# How to convert vertical string into horizontal in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

`O
N
K
A
R`

how to convert it into `ONKAR`. reverse of it I know. But this I am not able to solve.

Comment: Hi, try  [LISTAGG] https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "vertical string"? Are you showing rows from a table?Or Is it in a single row of a column?

Answer (score 3):

You *can't* do what you want generally without also having a second column which provides the ordering for each letter.  Assuming you do have a column for the position, we can try:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(letter, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY position) word
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

**Data:**

```
letter | position
O      | 1
N      | 2
K      | 3
A      | 4
R      | 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Listagg is right solution for strings up to 4000 bytes cuz it returns varchar2 data type. But for longer strings you may get clob data type.

```
with s (letter, position) as (
select 'O', 1 from dual union all
select 'N', 2 from dual union all
select 'K', 3 from dual union all
select 'A', 4 from dual union all
select 'R', 5 from dual)
select xmlcast(xmlagg(xmlelement(x, letter) order by position) as clob) c
from s;

C              
---------------
ONKAR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as long as data result has all rows that you want to stick together.

```
with data as (select 'O' as  letter from dual
              union all
              select 'N' from dual
              union all
              select 'K' from dual
              union all
              select 'A' from dual
              union all
              select 'R' from dual)
SELECT LISTAGG(letter, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rownum)
FROM data;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a single row separated by newline (ASCII 13) characters then you can just use `REPLACE( value, CHR(13) )`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT 'O' || CHR(13) || 'N' || CHR(13) || 'K' || CHR(13) || 'A' || CHR(13) || 'R' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT value, REPLACE( value, CHR(13) ) FROM test_data
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE     | REPLACE(VALUE,CHR(13))
:-------- | :---------------------
O         | ONKAR                 
N         |
K         |
A         |
R         |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=85516a0a1fc16c4b56c0e2d40f14f039)*